# Bluemix Push Service Error while registering device in Cordova App

Tags: cordova, push-notification, push, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to integrate Bluemix Push Notification Service in Cordova app using Cordova plugin. Following this http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/hybrid#push-operations. However, I'm facing the following error when I register device as follows,

```
var push = IBMPush.getService();
var alertNotification = function(message) {

    IBMBluemix.getLogger().info("Received notification");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
}
//Register the device
push.registerDevice("MyDeviceName", "UserName", "alertNotification").done(function(response) {
    console.log("device registration done successfully with response : ", response);
}, function(err) {
    console.log("ERROR in device registration : ", err);
});
```

**ERROR in device registration : Status Code : 403, Status Line : Forbidden**

1. I'm successfully able to initialize IBMPush service. This confirms that I'm using the right app id and app secret.
2. I also cross checked that I'm using the right Sender Id (Project number from Google Console) and API Key (Server key under API Credentials) in Bluemix Push Service and also ensured Google Cloud Messaging for Android API is Enabled.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using? The MBaaS plugin you are using has issues working with versions above 4.3. A completely rewritten Cordova SDK is in active development if using an old version of Cordova is not ideal for your application.

Comment: I'm using Cordova version 5.4.1! Are you sure this works in 4.3 and lower? And do you have any idea on how long it may take for them to support the latest versions of Cordova?

Comment: I cannot guarantee it's the only issue you are hitting but I can guarantee you will not get it to work on anything above 4.3 using that plugin. We are currently anticipating the new Cordova SDK to release before year's end. If you want to wait it out I can reply on here once it's launched if you would like.

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM Great! That ain't far from now. And yeah sure, it would certainly help if you could leave a comment here once it's launched! Thanks

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM I found out that I was trying to use IBM Push Notifications Service with this code but the SDK for that is likely to be launched by year end as you said. All I needed to add is Push service in Bluemix for it to work. It works fine now even with Cordova 5.4.1. Thanks anyways! And please leave a comment here once the SDK for 2nd Gen Push Notifications Service is launched.

Answer (score 0):

Our new Bluemix Mobile Services Hybrid SDK has been released which works with the latest version of Cordova. Following this the old "mbaas" Cordova SDK has been deprecated in favor of the new and improved version.

You can find the new open source cordova plugins on our Github at https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-core and https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push

For utilizing push I would recommend taking a look at our [HelloPush Cordova sample](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush) and running through the README found there, do note that you will need to create a new backend with the new services to properly utilize the new SDK.